# Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'. when running expo EAS services

Tags: react-native, gradle, expo, gradlew, expo-eas

When I try to build my expo react native app using expo EAS services I get this error as follows,

```
Please consult deprecation warnings for more details.
426 actionable tasks: 426 executed
[stderr] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[stderr] * What went wrong:
[stderr] Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
[stderr] > Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
[stderr] * Try:
[stderr] > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
[stderr] > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
[stderr] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[stderr] BUILD FAILED in 3m 8s
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.
```

my  eas.json looks like this,

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 2.4.1"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "image": "ubuntu-18.04-jdk-11-ndk-r19c"
      }
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

my app configuration is as follows,

```
minSdkVersion = '21'
buildToolsVersion = '31.0.0'
compileSdkVersion = '33'
targetSdkVersion = '33'
```

I'm trying to generate an apk here.
Can someone help, please

Comment: Did you scroll up in the log, the real cause of the issue should be logged somewhere above.

Comment: @Ferry Kranenburg Thanks I was able to fix it.

Comment: @hewa how did you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The real cause of the issue should be logged somewhere above